# Change username in VisualSVN

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We are using **VisualSVN** (free version) and have users in it with their firstnames as usernames. We now want to change the users to *firstname.lastname*.

VisualSVN does not seem to provide a function for this. I wonder if it is possible to change the usernames in the console perhaps. I cannot find any information on it because most of the related problems lead to changing the user of e.g. a commit. But that is actually exactly what I want to keep in tact. I could of course delete the users and create new ones but I actually want the commits to still be related to the correct users.

Comment: If my answer is the accepted answer for the question then you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer, so that it becomes green. If you found a different solution then you should describe it here and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (not much) strings that denote revision authors, and that are stored with every commit in property `svn:author`, are just strings. There are no relations to be made with some VisualSVN user database. The string can be changed to anything, including to something that is not a username.

Best (and AFAIK also only) course of action is to remove existing users, add new users, and run some [script](https://www.tty1.net/blog/2008/svn-author-renaming_en.html) on all repositories to rename `svn:author` property for every revision.